# c++ if what is the error in that code?

Tags: c++

hi my english is not very good
down i have the source code that i wrote
"if" and "else if" no problem with the print
but "else" problem I can not print

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x, y;
    char a,b;
    bool tm, mf;
    y = 13;
    b = 'A';

    cout <<"Asagidaki toplama islemini yap !"<< endl <<  "12" << endl << "+" << endl << "1" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    mf = (x == y);
    cout << "Turkiyenin baskenti'nin bas harfini" << endl << "buyuk harfle yaz" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    tm = (a == b);
    if (tm == mf == 1 )
        cout << "zekisin";
    else if (tm == 1)
        cout << "TM";
    else if (mf == 1)
        cout << "MF";
    else 
        cout << "Basaramadin";

    cin >> a;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tm == mf == 1` is incorrect.

To check if both `tm` and `mf` are equal to `1`, do this:

`if(tm == 1 && mf == 1)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in C++ you don't compare a bool value with 0/1, instead when you check true/false just check if it is != 0 e.g `if (tm) ...` so to check if both tm and mf are true write `if (tm && mf) ...`

Answer (score 0):

there is no any error on your code, 
but i think you mean why this output appeared for you. 
check your conditions in " if (tm == mf == 1 ) " 
this will print to you just three output which it was ( zekisin or TM or MF) 
and it will not print Basaramadin never because in your code you will not reach this condition, 
in "if (tm == mf == 1 )" if tm == mf will print zekisin, and if mf ==1 will print MF, if tm == 1 will print TM, 
and what you have missed as i think that if tm boolen was false which it means its value was 0 and also mf boolean was false with value 0 
your condition in  "if (tm == mf == 1 )" also will be right (true) because tm==mf and then this will print to you this "zekisin" 
and you will not reach to last else condition  " Basaramadin "
i hope this help you .